# you may need to install the My::Module module

Tags: java, perl

i work now in a project of web vulnerability scanner so i would run my perl script into my java the perl script is the uniscan open source tool from kali linux so when i click go to run the script this message appear

> Can't locate Uniscan/Crawler.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Uniscan::Crawler module) (@INC contains: ./Uniscan C:/Perl64/site/lib
>   C:/Perl64/lib .) at C:\uniscan\uniscan.pl line 25. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at test\uniscan.pl line 25.

However when i run hello world script it appear correctly with no probleme in my console. So this is my code of calling perl script in my java

```
try {
                String[] commande = {"perl", "C:\\uniscan\uniscan.pl"};
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commande);
                AfficheurFlux fluxSortie = new AfficheurFlux(p.getInputStream());
                AfficheurFlux fluxErreur = new AfficheurFlux(p.getErrorStream());

                new Thread(fluxSortie).start();
                new Thread(fluxErreur).start();

                p.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the code of uniscan is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/uniscan/code/ci/ef359f890ddff036544d6a733d540ebfd9be6981/tree/)

Please i need help i'm blocked is for my final degree next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program relies on the script's directory being found in the module search path (`@INC`), but does not ensure this.

If you run the script from the script's directory, it works because `.` is in `@INC` by default. But you are running the script from a different directory.

Remove the following useless line:

```
use lib "./Uniscan";
```

Replace it with the following:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

Comment: thank you for helping me but it is the same problem he told me "Can't locate Uniscan/Crawler.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Uniscan::Crawler module) (@INC contains:" any suggestions ?

Comment: thx it seems work your answer but i found another prob
1- "ERROR: Could not open uniscan.conf for read: No such file or directory" however i have file "uniscan.conf"
2-"Compilation failed in require at path/Uniscan/Crawler.pm line 4" and in line 4 there is use Uniscan::Http;
3-"BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at path/Uniscan/Crawler.pm line "
4-"Compilation failed in require at path\uniscan.pl line 25." and in line 25 use Uniscan::Crawler;
5-"BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at path\uniscan.pl line 25."

Comment: Apparently, it makes the same assumption in other places too. Just start the program with `C:` as the current drive and `\uniscan` as its current directory.

Comment: :( same problem too thank you anyway i hope that i will find a solution